# Dynamically updating content of drop down menu when radio button value is changed using PHP, MySQL and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

I am creating a form and in it there are two radio buttons and a drop down list. I want when a user changes their choice of radio button, the drop down list also changes its values which will picked from  a database table with two columns with names life and general.

Here is a snippet of the request.php

```html
    <input type="radio" name="department" id="department" value="life" onchange="listDept(this.value)" checked>Life
    <input type="radio" name="department" id="department" value="general">General 
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <select name="department" id="listDept">
 </select>
```

Here is the getdepartment.php file to query the database:

```html
<?php
require 'connectdb.php';

$department =NULL;
if(isset($_POST['department'])){$department = $_POST['department']; } 

if($department == "life")
{
 $query = "select life from tbl_departments";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  echo '<option>'.$row['life'].'</optiom>>';
}
if($department == "general")
{
 $query = "select general from tbl_departments";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  echo '<option>'.$row['general'].'</option>';
}
```

Here is the AJAX script to check the user's choice:

```js
function listDept()
{
 var dept = document.getElementById("department").value;
 var xhr;
 if (window.XMLHTTPRequest) { //Mozilla, Safari...
  xhr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
 }
 else if (window.ActiveXObject) { //IE8 and older
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 var data = "department" + dept;
 xhr.open("POST", "./parse_files_php/getdepartment.php", true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhr.send(data);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = display_data;
 function display_data(){
  if(xhr.readyState==4){
   if (xhr.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("listDept").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
   }
   else {
    alert('There was a problem with the request.');
   }

  }
 }
}
```

I am not getting any feedback from the server i.e. the drop down list is not populated.

My database connections are working fine.

Comment: Can you tell us which part isn't working? Are you not getting data back from the server or is it not populating the select properly? Any JS errors?

Comment: @hukir am not getting any data from the server. The drop down list is not generated at all.

Comment: You have duplicate `id="department"`, remove that and get value this way: `var dept = document.getElementsByName("department")[0].value;`

Comment: A couple of things then. Your select has the same name as the radio buttons. The "general" radio button needs an onchange to call the js function listDept. If you call the getdepartment.php file directly in a browser, do you get the list of options back?

Comment: @skobaljic I have done that but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @hukir yes. When I run the queries separately, I get the list of options. I dunno how to run the queries without the if statements since it's supposed to get the the value from the $_POST. But tho when I run the the getdepartment.php file I get a blank white page which must it did not get any value from the form using $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

In case youre willing to use jquery for the page scripts for that one functionality
you can refer to my sample.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[name='department']").click(function() {
                    //console.log($('input:radio[name=department]:checked').val());
                    getSelectOptions($('input:radio[name=department]:checked').val());
                    //AJAX CALL
                });
            });

            function getSelectOptions(radioVal) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'dbo.php',
                    data: {'radioval': radioVal},
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);
                        updateSelect(data)
                    }
                });
            }

            function updateSelect(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(json);
                var selectHTML;
                $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                    selectHTML += "<option value=" + value + ">" + value + "</option>";
                });
                $('#listDept').html(selectHTML);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="department" id="department" value="life">Life
            <input type="radio" name="department" id="department" value="general">General 
            <select name="department" id="listDept">
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my dummy php file that returns the list entries which obviously will contain your database calls and so forth.

dbo.php

```
<?php
$radio=$_REQUEST['radioval'];
$selectArray=array();
if($radio=='life'){
$selectArray[0]='life1';
$selectArray[1]='life2';
}else if($radio=='general'){
$selectArray[0]='general1';
$selectArray[1]='general2';

}
echo json_encode($selectArray);
```

Try the sample and let us know if this works for you.